# MyBase.Load or Me.Load not firing while the form loads with no traceable error

Tags: vb.net, winforms, events, windows-forms-designer

I have a vb.net windows form that is not firing the form load handler when the form is open.  This happen after I manually edit the designer.vb file to add some new fields.  I've review a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129925/form-load-event-not-firing-form-showing), but after trying all the solution from that issue's suggested answer it didn't reveal any hidden errors the form may have hidden.

Some things to note, other events appears to be firing properly, like Me.FormClosed or Me.FormClosing.

Form_Load event sample code:

```
    Private Sub Form_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Try

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
```

Example of the changes I've made to the designer.vb file:

added

```
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Me.TextBox100 = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()

        '
        'TextBox100
        '
        Me.TextBox100.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Honeydew
        Me.TextBox100.DataBindings.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", Me.SomethingBindingSource, "NAME", True))
        Me.TextBox100.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill
        Me.TextBox100.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
        Me.TextBox100.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(414, 118)
        Me.TextBox100.Margin = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0)
        Me.TextBox100.Name = "TextBox100"
        Me.TextBox100.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(134, 22)
        Me.TextBox100.TabIndex = 47
        Me.TextBox100.TextAlign = System.Windows.Forms.HorizontalAlignment.Center
    End Sub

    Friend WithEvents TextBox100 As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
```

Any suggestion would be very helpful, Thanks

Comment: You probably shouldn't edit the designer file directly.  Make sure your `Me.SomethingBindingSource` isn't nothing.

Comment: This is undiagnosable from the provided info.  This does tend to happen when you stuff a hundred text boxes in a form and then start to edit the designer generated code by hand.  Use source control to rewind back to the last-known working version.

Comment: @LarsTech Thank you for you suggestion!  You are right I forgot to add a field for one of the textbox binding, which was causing an error for the form which prevented the from to trigger load handler.  I just wish it actually throw an error which would of help debug this issue much quicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add a field for one of the textbox binding, which was causing an error for the form which prevented the from to trigger load handler.