# MainForm_Load doesn't work c#

Tags: c#, winforms

The MainForm_Load doesn't work, the form is showing as I designed, but nothing in the load method happens. When I put a breakpoint it just skip on this method, I tried to delete the method and recreate it but it still not working.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010, everithing works fine with other projects I did.

Even the most basic function not working in it.
Here is an example:

```
    public FormMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void FormMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Test");
    }
```

Any ideas??
Tnx

Comment: Where are you calling FormMain_Load from?

Comment: you have some problem with your visual studio version.  Reinstall it and come baxk to us.

Comment: Check this out: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129925/form-load-event-not-firing-form-showing> and <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933958/vs2010-does-not-show-unhandled-exception-message-in-a-winforms-application-on-a>

Answer (score 6):

Did you type this by hand?

You need to assign the event, if you do this on the designer it will auto generate the code. If you want to do by hand you have to manually assign the event.

```
public FormMain()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.Load += FormMain_Load;
}
```

Comment: Tried it also, not working... event new EventHandler is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks fine here.Please check this.

Go to Properties window of your form(here it is FormMain.cs[Design] ). Click on event section. check in Load event your

```
FormMain_Load
```

method is defined or not ?

give the breakpoint and check it is calling or not.
 Give breakpoint on the form constructor .

And you need to check, From where you are calling this form ? 
if this form is the first form in your application, then go to Program.cs file. and check there this is available or not inside Main Function.

```
 Application.Run(new FormMain());
```

In FormMain.Designer.cs page check

```
  this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.FormMain_Load);
```

is available inside

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
}
```

or not?

Comment: i tried all of it. The method in properties form is defined with the exact same name of the method (FormMain_Load). I've already checked in the designer the EventHandler as you described and it exists

Comment: give the breakpoint and check it is calling or not. Give breakpoint on the form constructor

Comment: give the breakpoint and check it is calling or not. Give breakpoint on the form constructor. in program.cs inside main function do this   Application.Run(new FormMain());